# is there a relation between the arboricity of a graph and the average degree?

Tags: graph-theory

I am working with a simple undirected graph G without loops or multiple edges. The arboricity of G, denoted a(G), is the minimum number of forests that the edges of G can be edge-decomposed into.
I am trying to find a relation between the average degree and the arboricity of G.

Comment: What's the maximum number of edges in a forest made from the edges of $G$? 
Can you use this to find the maximum number of edges in a graph of arboricity $a(G)$?
And once you know this maximum number of edges, how can you bound the average degree?

Comment: I didn't understand your questions. The information that I have is that G is a simple undirected graph without loops or multiple edges. Let $\Delta_{avg}$ be the average degree on G. I am licking to find a bound on a(g) that has a relation to $\Delta_{avg}$